# Unable to set ExpiryTimeUtc field when sending C2D messages using IoT Hub

Tags: c#, azure, azure-iot-hub

Stack Overflow Question

I have a console application which can send messages to an Android device. Whenever I try to send a message which has set ExpiryTimeUtc, the serviceClient.SendAsync method throws an exception:

> Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Common.Exceptions.IotHubException: 
>   Tracking Id:{TRACKING_ID_OMITTED}-TimeStamp:09/24/2019 00:23:41-G:20-TimeStamp:09/24/2019 00:23:41
>      at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.AmqpServiceClient.SendAsync(String deviceId, Message message, Nullable`1 timeout)

I checked the code of the exception, and its `InvalidErrorCode`, which doesn't help at all.

Here is a snippet of what produced the exception (the exact same code works when `ExpiryTimeUtc` is not set:

```
var message = new Message();
message.MessageId = messageId;
message.Ack = DeliveryAcknowledgement.Full;

message.CreationTimeUtc = creationTime; 
message.ExpiryTimeUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.DateTime.AddMinutes(1);
message.Properties.Add("type", "TEST_TYPE");
message.Properties.Add("test_data", data);
message.Properties.Add("checksum", checksum);
message.Properties.Add("page", pageNumber.ToString());
message.Properties.Add("page_total", total);
```

I'm using `Microsoft.Azure.Devices v1.18.1` and `Microsoft.NETCore.App v2.1.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my test, `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.DateTime.AddMinutes(1)` doesn't set `Kind` property.

[image]

You can use `DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1)` instead. It will work.

[image]